# Migrating from SVN - Getting Hung Up on Basic Git Workflow

Tags: git, svn

Want to migrate from Subversion to Git.  Want to have a common central repository (origin) as well as the local repositories that developers will work in.  The idea is to update the local repository and then push to the central one.

Have been trying to work through various tutorials, but getting hung up.  It's a Windows environment.

As an illustration, set up the bat files below.  The intent is to set up 2 folders to act as Git repositories: Git remote (gitTestOrigin) and local (gitTestLocal).

Then set up gitTestOrigin as a remote to local.  Then create a file in local, add it to Git, commit it, and push it to origin.

When test.bat gets to the push, get the following messages (edited):

> remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch:
> refs/heads/master remote: error: By default, updating the current
> branch in a non-bare repository remote: is denied, because it will
> make the index and work tree inconsistent ...   ! [remote rejected]
> master -> master (branch is currently checked out) error: failed to
> push some refs to 'g:\gitTestOrigin'

One suggestion in another post about this error was to just make origin a bare repository. This does get me past the error.  But since I want the files in the central repository, doesn't help.

Obviously I'm missing something basic.  Any help appreciated.

[Note: this is set up to run on a G: drive, which is a testing drive on my machine.]
[Added the set-upstream to the push in response to an error message I was getting without it. ]

test.bat:

```
g:
cd \
md gitTestOrigin
cd \
md gitTestLocal
cd \gitTestOrigin
git init
cd \gitTestLocal
git init
git remote add origin g:\gitTestOrigin
git remote -v
git status
git fetch origin
rem adding file hi.text
@echo hi > hi.txt
git add hi.txt
git commit -m "new hi.txt"
git push --set-upstream g:\gitTestOrigin master
```

cleanup.bat

```
g:
cd \
rmdir /Q /S gitTestLocal
rmdir /Q /S gitTestOrigin
```

Comment: You generally *should* use a bare repository to act as a place for others to `git push` their commits. You generally *should not* use Git as a deployment system, so the fact that the bare repository has no commits checked out should be fine anyway: you'll want a deployment system to pick some commit(s) from the bare repository to deploy for production use, according to rules that are too complicated to express in Git directly.

Comment: The key here is to realize that Git doesn't really store *files*. Git stores *commits*. A repository consists of two databases. One holds commits and other internal Git objects, which one finds by hash IDs. This is the most important one by far. The second holds names, which are ways to find those hash IDs so that you can get to them in the first database (thus also pretty important in the end, but it exists so as to make the commit database *useful*). Any files you get when using Git are just the result of taking some commit and extracting it.

Comment: The files extracted from some given commit go into your *working tree*, so that they can be read and written. The definition of a bare repository is simply a repository where there is no working tree. You can still grab any commit out of this repository, though. (That's where your deployment system comes in.)

Comment: SVN is centralized: there's one repository somewhere, which holds every version of every file as an SVN commit. Users then pluck those files (or some subset) out of the central repository, and have only the files, not the commits. They make new commits by sending updated files to the server. In Git, on the other hand, *everyone has the entire set of commits*. Everyone makes their own new commits and just sends a whole commit, or set of commits, to any Git designated as a server.

Answer (score 0):

To create remote repo you need to add `--bare` option with `git init`
for pushing we can use reference origin which we added in repo `git push -u origin master`